# Looking for tips on debugging strange point-light shadow artifacts

Tags: 3d, rendering, vulkan, directx-12

This has had me stuck for a while, so I'm hoping someone can provide some wisdom (or at least some tips on how to figure out what the heck is going on!).

I have a renderer that supports DX11, DX12 and Vulkan, that supports some (pretty basic, just simple cubemap depth) shadows for point lights. At lower frame rates, these work just fine, but at crazy high frame rates and with the lights moving rapidly, I'm getting shadowing artifacts where it appears as if the shadow distance is off slightly compared to the light position. That's just a guess though, since if I pause, or do a frame capture in (for example) RenderDoc, the artifacts disappear. It's not been possible to grab a frame with the artifacts to debug, but I did manage to grab a screenshot. This only occurs when the light is moving away from the planar surface.

[image]

This only manifests with DX12 and Vulkan, but identical in both.

I fixed an issue a few weeks back where updates were out of order and the shadow generation was a frame behind the main rendering; this was pretty easy to repro and debug. This new case, not so much! Given the inability to repro when capturing, etc, it's been tough to track down.

I'd generally not be too concerned, since when rendering anything useful there's no issues since the framerate is lower, but I'm worried what I'm seeing is the result of something more systemic that'll bite me later.

Edit: So far, I've tried:

- RenderDoc (unable to grab a capture manifesting this issue - either by queueing captures or hitting F12 when it manifests)
- Debug visualizations - they show the issue, but as soon as I pause or perform a capture, the issue disappears.
- Tracy profiler to show timings of when constants are updated and when tasks are scheduled. There's nowhere near any overlap with updates and consumption of data.
- Putting small pauses in the main application loop. This fixes the issue (even a .5 millisecond pause on the main thread, which drops the fps from ~800fps to 600).

Comment: You really need to provide a summary of what you've tried so far, or you're just going to get a slew of "have you tried renderdoc?" comments.

Comment: If it's this timing sensitive it sounds like a missing dependency pipeline barrier somewhere.

Comment: As others noted we need more info. But this sounds like a sync issue. So how do you pass data to your shaders? Are you using one uniform buffer per frame? If not (and you only use a single one) how do you sync?

Comment: Instance data is push constants, other data is broken out into constant buffers in descriptor sets (for each pipeline layout, there's a set for per-frame, per-view and per-material). Similar pattern on DX12. It runs cleanly with the Vulkan validation layers enabled (which are amazingly good, by the way - they seem to catch everything!), which would indicate there's no missing pipeline barriers. I've also verified it's not a threading issue by forcing all updates onto one thread.

Comment: The default Vulkan layer configuration does not include validation for synchronization. If you want to validate that, run vkconfig (part of the SDK) and enable sync validation.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't looked at vkConfig - ran that, and it did give me some sync warnings on init that I can go fix, but sadly, this issue doesn't manifest with the validation layers active, and there's no warnings popping up during regular frame rendering.

Comment: I am seeing a bunch of "Hazard WRITE_AFTER_WRITE vs. layout transition" warnings on these shadow maps on the first frame - but these warnings don't show up later (even though it's the same renderpass/transition logic). Does the validation layer ignore subsequent instances of the same warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out, and, not surprisingly, it was a really silly mistake. But despite being rather dumb, it was also a fairly gnarly one to figure out, since there were no Vulkan validation errors/warnings, it was occurring both in DX12 and Vulkan, and was highly dependent on timing.

I figured I should post the solution, since if anyone else happens to make this same mistake (or something similar), and stumbles on this question, I could save them some pain.

So, here it is. My Vulkan uniform buffer implementation tries to be smart, and creates a queue of buffers that are tagged with the last frame they were consumed by rendering work. If there's an update to a uniform buffer, I check the front (oldest) element in the queue, and if it's frame is older than my frame buffering count, I'll re-use it (overwriting the uniform buffer data) for the next frame, and toss that buffer to the back of the queue.

However, I had an off-by-one error in that calculation (for both DX12 *and* Vulkan) due to the fact that there's some overlap between frame workloads, and that meant that, depending on timing, I'd be overwriting a uniform buffer while the GPU was still using it, so the GPU would be calculating point shadows with the *next* frame's light data. So, literally fixing that off-by-one, and adding an extra frame of buffering, fixed this annoying (random) issue.

Side note: always, always run regularly with the Vulkan validation layers enabled. Whilst occasionally cryptic, it's incredibly thorough and (outside of this case) has helped me catch numerous issues that would have been a nightmare to track down otherwise.